Derivative of geodesic $z^\mu(\lambda;x_i,x_f)$ respect to initial position $x_i$
I'm working on a problem on General Relativity where I use the geodesic $z^\mu(\lambda;x_i,x_f)$ parametrized by $\lambda$ that starts at $x_i$ and ends at $x_f$
$$ z^\alpha(\lambda_i)=x_i^\alpha\\ z^\alpha(\lambda_f)=x_f^\alpha$$
I am interested in calculating the derivative of this geodesic function respect to its initial position $$\frac{\partial z^\mu(\lambda;x_i,x_f) }{\partial x_i^\nu}$$
Some things I know
I know that it must satisfy the boundary conditions
$$ \frac{\partial z^\mu(\lambda_i;x_i,x_f) }{\partial x_i^\nu}=\delta_\nu^\mu\\ \frac{\partial z^\mu(\lambda_f;x_i,x_f) }{\partial x_i^\nu}=0$$
And I can easily calculate it in flat spacetime. Then, the geodesic is simply $$z^\mu(\lambda;x_i,x_f)=x^\mu_i +\frac{\lambda-\lambda_i}{\lambda_f-\lambda_i}\big(x_f^\alpha-x_i^\alpha\big)$$
So the derivative is
$$\frac{\partial z^\mu(\lambda;x_i,x_f) }{\partial x_i^\nu}=\frac{\lambda_f-\lambda}{\lambda_f-\lambda_i}\delta^\mu_\nu$$
But in general I'm having a hard time understanding if this object can be calculated or even what are its properties. Does it propagate vectors along the geodesic?
Relation to Geodesic deviation
We can think of the displacement in the initial condition as being parametrized by $$\delta x_i^\alpha=s\delta l^\alpha$$
Then we can think of a family of geodesics
$$z^\alpha(\lambda,s)\equiv z^\alpha(\lambda;x_i+s\delta l,x_f)$$
where $\lambda$ is the parameter along the curves while $s$ measures the displacement in the inital position.  The usual geodesic deviation vector is
$$\xi^\mu(\lambda,s)=\frac{\partial z^\alpha(\lambda,s)}{\partial s}|_{s=0}$$
and I know $\xi$ satisfies the geodesic deviation equiation and its acceleration can be calculated in terms of the Riemann tensor. I also know that $\xi$ relates to my object of interest in a simple way
$$\frac{\partial z^\mu(\lambda;x_i,x_f) }{\partial x_i^\nu}\delta l^\nu=\xi^\mu(\lambda)$$
We can think of $\delta l=\xi(\lambda=0)$ So it looks like my object propagates the geodesic deviation vector. I have also saw it is sometimes named Jacobi propagator
$$J^\mu_{\ \nu}(\lambda,\lambda_1 )=\frac{\partial z^\mu(\lambda;x_i,x_f) }{\partial x_i^\nu}$$
Which satisfies $$J^\mu_{\ \nu}(\lambda,\lambda_1 )\xi^\nu(\lambda_1)=\xi^\mu(\lambda)$$
Extra question
If general properties of the Jacobi propagator can't be known, I'd still be interested in knowing if there's any properties that could help me calculate the product of the tangent vector to the geodesic with the Jacobi propagator
$$g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dz^\mu(\lambda;x_i,x_f)}{d\lambda}J^\nu_{\ \alpha}$$
